# Play Framework put val into Action Builder Scala

Tags: playframework

I have custom Action Builder which must check my val for correct value

```
class CheckAction @Inject()(parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) {
    override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: Request[A] => Future[Result]) = {
    if (Base16.decode( HERE I NEED MY VAL).isSuccess) block(request) else resolve(Results.Forbidden)
  }
}
```

My route like this

```
GET        /api/block/:id      controllers.BlockController.findBlockApi(id: String)
```

And controller is

```
def findA(id: String): Action[AnyContent] = checkAction(id) {
....
```

So how can I put my :id from route to my custom action builder?

Answer (score 1):

Find answer.
1) ActionBuilder:

```
class Base16CheckAction(parser: BodyParsers.Default, modifierId: String) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) {
   override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: Request[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result] =
   if (Base16.decode(modifierId).isSuccess) block(request) else resolve(Results.BadRequest)
}

class Base16CheckActionFactory @Inject()(parser: BodyParsers.Default) {
  def apply(modifierId: String): Base16CheckAction = new Base16CheckAction(parser, modifierId)
}
```

2) Controller:

```
@Inject(base16Check: Base16CheckActionFactory...)
def findHeaderView(id: String): Action[AnyContent] = base16Check(id).async {
....
```